# Melhor estrutura HTML - Loja Virtual

Tags: html, html5, seo, semântica, w3c-validador

Fala galera, blz ?

Minha duvida é a seguinte, qual a melhor estrutura HTML para se montar uma loja virtual ? Levando em conta padrões de semântica e SEO.

Por exemplo:

- Eu devo usar `divs`, `li` ou `articles` na listagem dos produtos ?
- Ou devo utilizar `articles` apenas nas paginas de categorias e no restante `divs` ou `li` ?
- Posso utilizar `sections` dentro de `sections`, para separar os produtos em uma mesma pagina ?

Seria algo parecido com isso ?

```
...
<section>
    <header>
        Header Pagina
    </header>
    <section>
        <header>
            Categoria 1
        </header>
        <article>
            Produto
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header>
            Categoria 2
        </header>
        <article>
            Produto
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</section>
...
```

Comment: Isso não existe: _"Minha duvida é a seguinte, qual a melhor estrutura HTML para se montar uma loja virtual ? Levando em conta padrões de semântica e SEO."_ - Você tem que fazer a estrutura de acordo com o que vai acontecer com seu site, não tem como dar uma resposta pronta pra isso. Não teria como alguém te dar uma resposta que servisse pra qualquer situação. Já considerou a possibilidade de contratar um profissional da área?

Comment: Outra alternativa, se realmente está procurando uma "solução enlatada" é olhar os sites existentes no mercado e "se inspirar" pelo fonte deles, mas já adianto: muitos dos grandes portais nacionais de comércio eletrônico são forrados de serviço porco, então há o risco de você copiar porcaria. Notar que eu acho boa sua iniciativa em aprender a fazer certo, o alerta do primeiro comentário tem a intenção de você entender que não é simples assim, e que vai ter que se empenhar um bocado se quiser fazer por conta própria. Mas aí, vai ter que ser mais específico e pontual nas perguntas.

Comment: Aqui tem umas dicas pra fazer a pergunta ficar mais relevante: [ask] - Note que enquanto não tem respostas, você pode [edit] a pergunta à vontade e torná-la mais específica, dividindo sua dúvida em partes menores e possíveis de serem respondidas no formato Pergunta Objetiva -> Resposta Objetiva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara a tua pergunta não tem resposta porque não existe HTML estruturado para sites do tipo a ou b, o HTML é para estruturar como os elementos vão ser exibidos. Tentando te ajudar vou dizer o seguinte:

- Pensando em otimizar o teu código para SEO sempre use HTML5, já que suas tags são procuradas pelos motores de busca por conta da semântica.
- Estuda bem a finalidade de cada tag nova do HTML5 para não usá-las em contextos errados.
- Código não é a coisa mais importante em se tratando de SEO, pense nisso e da uma pesquisada.
- Eu devo usar divs, li ou articles na listagem dos produtos ? Ou devo utilizar articles apenas nas paginas de categorias e no restante divs ou li ? Não sei te responder porque isso depende de como vai ser estruturada a página.
- Posso utilizar sections dentro de sections, para separar os produtos em uma mesma pagina ? Sim, section pode ficar dentro de outra section, isso não tem restrição, mas se vai atender a tua necessidade isso depende do conteúdo e da estrutura da página.